# Modular exponentiation with the Carmichael function

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, totient-function, carmichael-function

This is something I have been thinking of using in a math competition against other players so it would be very helpful to me if it was explained.

How would someone reduce a problem such as $\frac{7^{54}}{11}$ mod 11 or any problem in the form $\frac{a^b}{c} \bmod \{7,8,9,10,11\} $ with the Carmichael function?

In the problem I've listed, $\lambda(11^2)=110$
but I do not know where to go from here.

I know that half of 110 is 55, and the exponent 54 is one less than 55 . But I'm not sure how to apply this piece of information.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Do you mean $7^{54} \mod{11}\equiv 3$ or do you genuinely mean $\frac{7^{54}}{11} \mod{11}\equiv \frac{69}{11}$?

Comment: I mean (7^54)/11 mod 11 because without the problem being over 11, it would be much easier.

Comment: Also sorry for not using formatting. I haven't learned how to do it yet.

Comment: @Vate if my edit is approved, check the edit log for showing formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if we want to find for example
$$x\equiv\frac{7^{54}}{13} \mod{11}$$
$$13x\equiv7^{54} \mod{11}$$
Now because $\lambda(11)=10$ and $\gcd{(7,11)}=1$ we now have that
$$7^{10}\equiv1\mod{11}$$
$$\therefore 7^{54}\equiv7^4\equiv49^2\equiv5^2\equiv25\equiv3\mod{11}$$
So we now have to solve
$$13x\equiv3\mod{11}$$
which has solutions
$$x\equiv7\mod{11}$$

Comment: I understood how the solutions for the problem you've stated were derived but I still don't understand how $\frac{7^{54}}{11} \mod{11}\equiv \frac{69}{11}$.

Comment: Sorry, I typed it into Wolfram: Alpha and that was the given result. The value of $\frac{7^{54}}{11}\mod{11}$ is undefined as the denominator of the fraction is divisible by the modulo. In general $\frac{a}{b} \mod{b}$ is undefined. The fraction $\frac{69}{11}$ is just the value of $\frac{7^{54} \mod{121}}{11}$

Comment: Would it still be undefined if the solutions could be rational?

Comment: It is undefined as it requires some $x$ to exist such that $ax\equiv k \mod{a}$ where $k\ne0$ and since $ax$ is divisible by $a$ we must have that $ax\equiv0\mod{a}$ - a contradiction.